# VueJS - Sorting array of objects coming from the API response

Tags: vue.js, sorting, object

I am trying to assign the variable to the vue-select by response coming from the API.
Here is the scenario i have two components, which is shown below:

**FirstPage.vue**

```
      <div class="vx-col" v-for="automobile in automobiles" v-bind:key="automobile.id">
          <vx-card>
              <div class="content">
                <vs-button class="btn" @click="$router.push({name: 'Go_to_info', params: {uni_id: automobile.uni_id.toString() }}).catch(err => {})">Touch to see info</vs-button>
              </div>
          </vx-card>
     </div>
    ....
 automobiles: []    
    ....
 created () {
     this.$http.get('/automobiles')
    .then((response) => { this.automobiles = response.data })
 }
```

**Info.vue**

```
  <div class="select">
    <vselect v-model="input1" :options="[{label: [automobiles[$route.params.uni_id].name}]" />
  </div>
     ....
 automobiles: []    
    ....
 created () {
     this.$http.get('/automobiles')
    .then((response) => { this.automobiles = response.data })
 }
```

**Response from /automobiles:**

```
   [
      {
        "uni_id": 3,
        "name": "Benz",        <---- This object becomes index[0]
      },
      {
        "uni_id": 1,
        "name": "Suzuki",      <---- This object becomes index[1]
      },
       {
        "uni_id": 4,
        "name": "Audi",        <---- This object becomes index[2]
      },
       {
        "uni_id": 2,
        "name": "Honda",       <---- This object becomes index[3]
      } 
   ]
```

So how can i sort my response using javascript only, and then how can i use the response of FirstPage.vue in the info.vue because i am making the same call in info.vue. Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a computed property on your component that sorts the array, and then iterate over that:

```js
created() {
    this.fetchAutomobiles();
},
computed: {
    automobilesSorted() {
        return this.automobiles.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        });
    }
},
data() {
    return {
        automobiles: []
    };
},
methods: {
    fetchAutomobiles() {
        this.$http.get('/automobiles').then((response) => {
            this.automobiles = response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="vx-col" v-for="automobile in automobilesSorted" v-bind:key="automobile.id">
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the index and $route.params.uni_id numbers to be compared if same, say if $route.params.uni_id is 3, then the index becomes [3] and then it should contain uni_id 3"s information.

Comment: @build___ That’s not what your question asks, though. You can find the item with the find method on Array.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is sort the array by its property after it is received.

For example if you want to sort by automobile's name, you can do this:

```
created () {
  this.$http.get('/automobiles')
    .then((response) => { 
       this.automobiles = response.data.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name); 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the index and $route.params.uni_id numbers to be compared if same, say if $route.params.uni_id is 3, then the index becomes [3]  and then it should contain uni_id 3"s information.